# Persistent sln change demands to be saved when building or changing branches

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, sln-file

I updated visual studio 2022 to version 17.3.1. Now when even, I build or try to change branches it asks me to save changes to the sln file. However, I get an error if I try to save it. It just says "parameter". It won't let me build unless I get rid of the change by switching branches and it deletes the change. However, it just comes back later.

Comment: What does the diff look like on your solution file? What is it trying to change?

Comment: @TimothyG. I can't view the diff. It refuses to open it.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find this workaround that seems to be working for me. Though it appears to me the startup process is crazy slow now.

They do say it will be fixed in the next big release of 17.4

> Thank you for providing more information! We found the root cause of the issue is a regression in 17.3 and are working on a fix in an
> upcoming release. The bug appears to be processing the
> “FolderStartupService” sections of the .sln file.
>
> As a workaround, you can remove all the instances of this section from
> your solution files:

```
 ProjectSection(FolderStartupServices) = postProject
    {B4F97281-0DBD-4835-9ED8-7DFB966E87FF} =
 {B4F97281-0DBD-4835-9ED8-7DFB966E87FF} EndProjectSection
```

> From our investigation, this particular service guid appears to have been
> removed around VS 2010. Since this service guid no longer exists,
> removing it should have no side effects.

[Unable-to-save-sln-file-changes](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-save-sln-file-changes/10120367)